# Where can I get a Portal mod for Minecraft multiplayer?

Tags: mods, minecraft-java-edition

I have made my own Minecraft server that isn't using Bukkit and I need the warp commands and a teleporter mod for it but can only find ones for Bukkit.

Is there a site where I can find these mods without Bukkit? If not, is it possible to change to Bukkit instead of making a whole new Bukkit server?

Comment: Are you asking if it's possible to add Bukkit to an existing server without creating a whole new world?  I believe the answer is yes, just follow the instructions on the Bukkit site (make sure to backup your world regardless)

Answer (score 2):

To change a server to Bukkit, you just need to run the Bukkit installer, then replace the world folder in the .bukkit folder with the world folder from your server.

Comment: I know that when using the jars by themselves (my server runs on linux) when you run Bukkit for the first time in a server folder that had been running vanilla it will reconfigure your Nether and End folders - will this work with your solution?

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure. I haven't run a Bukkit server since 1.0. As far as I know, it should. One of my friends often runs a Bukkit server for us, and we've imported vanilla worlds before. I would recommend not running bukkit in the same folder, but in a different one, then just copying the vanilla world folder over the bukkit world folder, so you can be sure it works.